# How can I scale an array to new array of different size

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array of integer, and it's length is fixed, and the array contains 0 or 1. And I need to scale this array to new array with different size and it's size can be less than or greater than input.

For example,

```
input = 1,0,1,0,1 //input size 5
output = 1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1 //out put size 10
```

The problem comes here, suppose the input is repeat of 1 and 0 in random order, I need to scale to new array of different size, how it's possible?.

Like

```
input 1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0......// n size random repeat of 0 and 1 
output ?,?,?.....................// of m
```

Actually I have to plot the input array in graph ,  the input array will be fixed length, and I need to scale this array to another array of different size, as I have to plot for different screen size.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to actually do. Can you provide some example input and output?

Comment: Why do you need the normalization?  How is the new array larger than the original?

Comment: Normalization I meant I need to extent the array element to new array and it's size can be greater than or less than the input array

Comment: Will the extension always be double/triple/etc?  Will shrinks always be half/third/quarter/etc?  Or is a shrink from 5->4 allowed?

Comment: No it can be any value......

Comment: Use `std::bitset` or `std::vector`.  They magically change their size during run time as required.

Comment: I still don't understand how to derive `b` from `a`.  Unless your issue is about reallocating an array.

Comment: The OP is asking for **interpolation** of binary vectors, i think..

Comment: My interpretation was Nearest Neighbor interpolation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering#Nearest-neighbor_interpolation

Comment: Hi all thanks for your  valuable comments and answer, I have edited my question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It's better than it was, but still pretty unclear. Do you have a clear algorithm in mind to determine the output values based on the input values?

Comment: This definitely looks like Nearest Neighbour Interpolation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following may help: (https://ideone.com/xS1f0C)

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void normalizebyIndex(const int (&src)[N], int (&dest)[M])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != M; ++i) {
        dest[i] = src[i * N / M];
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you derive the formula?

Comment: As I understand, OP wants something like scaling array (as we can do for image). Here I use something near of nearest-neighbor interpolation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling.

Comment: It's not quite nearest-neighbor, it's a little more like nearest-left.  But here's more samples: https://ideone.com/bNDQAP